# Implement value in different types

Tags: java

I have a Java classes `CancelRequest` used as DTO into Rest API. Unfortunately I have to recreate it from scratch.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class CancelRequest {
   private long accountNumber; // what should be this type

   public void setAccountNumber(String number) {
    if (number!=null) {
        this.accountNumber = Long.parseLong(number);
    }
   }
}
```

The problem is that I need to use sometimes `accountNumber` as `Long` value and sometimes like `String` value like this:

```
class SomeObject {

   String StringSome1Value;
}   
    
someObject.setStringSome1Value(Long.toString(cancelRequest.getAccountNumber()));

.....

class SomeSecObject{

   String StringSome2Value;
}
              
someSecObject.setStringSome2Value(cancelRequest.getAccountNumber());
```

Is there some solution to this problem?

Comment: What's the problem? The code you showed is correct.

Comment: Sorry I was not very clear. In some cases `accountNumber` is expected to be String. In other cases it's expected to be Long.

Comment: @PeterPenzov What about using `Object` as the type? It can fit a `String` and the wrapper class `java.lang.Long`. Is it an option to use generics?

Comment: If I set it to Object I get `Required type: long, Provided: Object`

Comment: @PeterPenzov You might need to cast the `Object` value to a `Long` object, then it will automatically unbox it to a `long` value. But it is still unclear what you are trying to do. Please edit your question to include a more detailed description of what you are trying to do and what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem as if you are using Lombok to implement Getters and Setters.  But if a setter is explicitly found in your code, Lombok should ignore it (or you could remove the `@Setter` annotation).  Create then, a setter like this:

```
    public void setAccountNumber(Object number) {
        if (number!=null) {
            accountNumber = number.toString();
        }
        else {
            accountNumber = null;
        }
    }
```

If the passed `accountNumber` object was a String, then performing a `.toString()` on that works just fine.

Comment: I get Required type: long, Provided: String

Comment: Sorry I was not very clear. Please see my updated post.

Comment: Still not sure what you want to do.  Is it about SETTING the `accountNumber` inside `CancelRequest` or GETTING the `accountNumber` from the object and using it elsewhere?

Comment: I want to get the value from `CancelRequest`  Object.

Comment: I have extended the answer a bit more.

Comment: Looks like I found one solution valid for all cases. Please see the updated post. What should be the proper handling of the value into the `setAccountNumber` method?